# implicit declaration of function 'execle' error

Tags: c, c99

I keep getting

> implicit declaration of function 'execle' is invalid in C99

when compiling the code below. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=PEACH and apple", NULL};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  execle ("diner_info", "diner_info", "4", NULL, my_env);
  printf ("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf ("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE"));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before using *any* library function, read its man page to find out what header(s) you need to include.

Answer (score 5):

In `C99`, the implicit declaration of a function is not allowed. That means, the compiler should be aware of the function signature before it encounters a call to that function. This can be achieved two ways:

1. Define the function before using it.
2. Provide a forward declaration of the function and define it later.

Usually, the function signature is provided as a forward declaration through the header files.

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execle) of `execle()`, you need to include `unistd.h` to get the forward declaration.

Comment: That did get the warning to go but the program still does nothing. Just sits there doing nothing. goodsubject-lm:chap9 varunvb$ gcc diner_info.c -o diner_info && ./diner_info

Comment: @Ani: What would you expect the program to do? From the `exec*()` man-page: "*The `exec()` functions only return if an error has have occurred.*""

Comment: @alk Why would the printf statements don't work. printf ("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf ("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE"));  I thought they'd print out Diners: 4 and Juice: PEACH and apple

Comment: `execle` doesn't return unless there's an error, so any following code will not be executed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include **unistd.h** to resolve the implicit dec warning

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. That's the order the statements should be as it turns out. Anything after execle won't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


  char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=PEACH and apple", NULL};
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  printf ("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf ("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE"));
  execle ("diner_info", "diner_info", "4", NULL, my_env);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
# :$ gcc diner_info.c -o diner_info && ./diner_info 
Diners: (null)
Juice: (null)
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
Diners: 4
Juice: PEACH and apple
```

But I still don't understand why the null values on the top, though.

Comment: Well the nulls are because main doesn't run the execle before the printfs. :-/

Comment: actually your last posted code doesn't quite work.  Suggest always compiling with all warnings enabled, then the compiler will tell you that the main parameter 'argc' is not used.  argc should always to be checked before attempting to use any of the command line args, to assure the desired args actually exist.

Comment: this code: 'printf ("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]);' is getting a NULL value because the first command line argument does not exist.   this code: 'char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=PEACH and apple", NULL};' does not actually place the JUICE entry in the environment. so when trying to extract it from the environment, the code sees a NULL pointer

Comment: the execle() function only returns if an error occurs.  So it continues to spawn a new instance of the diner_info executable.  this will result in a massive number of processes, all (except last) waiting for execle to return (which it does not, unless an error occurs.)

Comment: @user3629249 why does not the environment setting JUICE stick ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have this all wrong and just in case someone else is running into this problem I'm submitting this. I'm also reading the head first c book as well and came across this section. I think you need two programs one should be named "dinner_info"

```
//dinner_info.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Dinners: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Juice: %s\n",getenv("JUICE"));
    return 0;

}
```

and the other should be your driver program say my_exec_program where you need to include the header unistd.h as you will be calling the `execle` function

```
//my_exec_program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char * my_env[] = {"JUICE=peach and apple", NULL};
    execle("dinner_info", "dinner_info", "4" , NULL , my_env);
}
```

pay special attention to how you set the JUICE environment variable there should be no spaces between JUICE, equal sign and peach. I kept getting null values for JUICE because of this omission.

So what is happening here, You're calling a program that calls another program and passing in an environment variable to the called program using the function `execle`.